# C while loop condition

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm reading Computer Systems for my CS class and I've come across a while loop condition that's puzzling me, here's the code:

```
int parseline(char *buf, char **argv)
{
    char *delim; /* Points to first space delimiter */
    int argc; /* Number of args */
    int bg; /* Background job? */

    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = ’ ’; /* Replace trailing ’\n’ with space */
    while (*buf && (*buf == ’ ’)) /* Ignore leading spaces */
        buf++;

     /* Build the argv list */
     argc = 0;
     while ((delim = strchr(buf, ’ ’))) {
         argv[argc++] = buf;
         *delim = ’\0’;
          buf = delim + 1;
          while (*buf && (*buf == ’ ’)) /* Ignore spaces */
              buf++;
     }
```

In

```
while (*buf && (*buf == ’ ’)) /* Ignore spaces */
```

the `while` loop has two operands to logical `&&` but I don't understand what is the purpose of the first operand `(*buf)`. The second operand is checking for empty space, but I would think that the second operand by itself would suffice for the purpose of this loop.

Comment: What would happen if buf == NULL? I tried running a simplified version of code with buf == NULL and got a seg fault because, from what I'm guessing, the loop condition tried to deference a NULL pointer. Is this bad programming practice to have a pointer in the loop condition? Should a loop with a flag condition be utilized instead?

Comment: `buf` cannot be `NULL` after this: `buf = delim + 1;`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `*buf &&` is superfluous.

---

`*buf` is false for `'\0'` and true for everything else.

`*buf == ' '` is true for `' '` and false for everything else, *including* `'\0'`.

Comment: another approach: `(*buf && (*buf == ’ ’))`: when `*buf==' '` the first condition is true as well so it's redundant all right

Answer (score 1):

The following is functionally the same as `while (buf == ' ')` if the quote marks `’` are changed to `'`.

```
//                      v-v--- not standard quote marks.
while (*buf && (*buf == ’ ’))
```

With a good compiler, neither is faster as an optimizing compiler with emit the same code.

To me it is simply pedantic code insuring the loop is not taken with a *null character*.

---

What is bad about the code includes:

`buf[strlen(buf)-1] = ’ ’;` is a UB if `buf[0] == 0`.

`buf[strlen(buf)-1] = ’ ’; /* Replace trailing ’\n’ with space */` may lop off a non-`'\n'`.

A better alternative that address the 2 preceding concerns: `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';`

Instead of "Ignoring spaces", it is more C-like to ignore *white-spaces*.

"Build the argv list" usually requires a final `argv[argc] == NULL`.

Of course these are sides issues to the main question and without the larger context may/may not apply.

Answer (score 1):

> The second operand is checking for empty space, but I would think that
>   the second operand by itself would suffice for the purpose of this
>   loop.

```
  while (*buf && (*buf == ’ ’)) /* Ignore leading spaces */
        buf++;
```

It would suffice. The loop would break for `*buf == '\0'`.